# How can I prevent the user from typing at the very bottom of a scrollable textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, vertical-scrolling

If you are reading this, I hope you are well!

I have **cheesy, basic code editor** and I am trying to figure out the **best approach for adding space to the bottom of the textarea** so that the user is not always typing at the very bottom of the textarea, e.g., once things begin to overflow/scroll.  I guess something similar to CodePen itself :)

This one is tricky because I have **two absolutely-positioned divs, side-by-side** (the line numbers and the lines, respectively) and I have **synchronized the scrolling**.  Now, add on top of that, the requirement to add some space, and I am stuck!

Here is a detailed CodePen mock up that shows my work-in-progress code: [CodePen: Textarea with Line Numbers](https://codepen.io/babalugats76/pen/pojoGVV)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bulk-editor .editor").bind("input propertychange", function() {
    var lineCount = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
    $(".lines").text('');
    for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i) {
      $(".lines").append("<span class='linenum'></span>");
    }
  });

  $('.editor').scroll(function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.lines').scrollTop(top);
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 16px 0;
}

.bulk-editor {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  counter-reset: matches;
  outline: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bulk-editor-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 1rem;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: inherit;
}

.linenum {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  &::before {
    counter-increment: matches;
    content: counter(matches);
  }
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: grey;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: inherit;
  &:focus {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Refer to this article https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5163219/HTML-Line-Numbering-using-textarea -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="bulk-editor">
    <div class="bulk-editor-wrapper">
      <div class="lines"></div>
      <textarea class="editor" rows="10" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[image: How Can I Add Bottom Padding...]

[image: If I Simply Add Bottom Padding]

I am struggling to determine the correct approach. Can this be done using **pure CSS** or is a more complex **JavaScript solution using scroll events** required?

If anyone has experienced a similar requirement and knows a sane approach, I am all ears. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add the padding-bottom you want for both `.lines` and `.editor`, i.e. 20px;

```css
.lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 1rem;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 60px !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: grey;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  &:focus {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Then, you check if you are in the last line of the editor to scroll down.
Inside the function for the `input propertychange` event, add this:

```js
if (this.selectionStart === this.value.length) {
  $(this).scrollTop($(this).prop("scrollHeight"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Azametzin!  I really appreciate you taking the time.  I did originally try that but found that when I did that the textarea's contents were getting clipped and the line numbers were undisturbed--things simply didn't line up.  Try scrolling up on this CodePen and you should be able to see the clip: [Textarea with Line Numbers Azametzin Edition](https://codepen.io/babalugats76/pen/WNQQmZZ). I have been testing in Firefox.

Comment: I just found out that padding in textarea behaves differently in Firefox, so another approach is needed. I will try to solve this in a few days.

Comment: Thanks @Azametzin!  You are awesome.  I am continuing to work on something on my end as well. As is too often the case, it might involve some wrapper hell :) Hopefully, we can come up with something that might help others.  An acceptable solution would have users having the ability to scroll up to position where they are typing.  There is no need to hijack the scroll, but making sure they are not stuck at the bottom is all I am looking for.  My use case is unique in that users get to enter a max # of lines, so a solution that pre-populates the line numbers can work in our favor.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on creating a text editor, so I went through the same problems. I found it easier to make the textarea expand to the size of the code instead of syncronizing the scrolling.

```js
function updateSize(){
    var code = document.getElementById("code"); //the textarea
    var codeHighlight = document.getElementById("codeHighlight"); //the highlighted code
    var longestLine = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < code.value.split("\n").length; i++) {
        if(code.value.split("\n")[i].length > longestLine){
            longestLine = code.value.split("\n")[i].length;
        }
    }
    code.style.width = (longestLine+2) + "ch";
    code.style.height = 13.33333*1.15*(code.value.split("\n").length+1) + "px";

    codeHighlight.style.width = (longestLine+3) + "ch";
    if(longestLine == 0 && code.value.split("\n").length == 1){
        //make it visible if there is no text
        code.style.width = "100px";
        code.style.height = "100px";
    }
}
document.onkeyup = updateSize();
```

I have a smaller textarea on top of a div with highlighted syntax. Right after the user presses a key, the code changes the size of the textarea to just cover the text. I found it helpful to also specify the following CSS on top of the other css:

```css
#code{
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
}
```

Where `#code` is the textarea.

I have a link to what I did [here](http://kiraprograms.com/blue/) and also [here](http://kiraprograms.com/blue/script.js). Not all of the code is relevant, but look into the function updateHighlight() and the div editMode.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Kira!  I appreciate your time. In my case, I have line numbers that I want to put alongside the code. I am synchronizing the scroll, more than else, to lines those up. Can you add some context to your suggestion and how it might be used to get that bottom padding I am trying to accomplish while still having lined up code and lines numbers that can be synchronously scrolled? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Kira. This is pretty cool.  I am going to study your code and see if there are some things that I would be wise to apply to my use case.I am working on a revamped version of my own that might at least give the user to ability to always have spaces at the bottom (if they want it). Every editor is a totally different use case it seems but I can definitely learn from something even if it isn't 1:1.  Many Thanks!